# After I restart PostgreSQL all my tables are empty (zero rows)

Tags: database, macos, postgresql

Using Mac OS X 10.10 (Yosemite) and Homebrew (0.9.5), I've installed PostgreSQL 9.4.1. Basically all current versions as of the time of this posting...

I've successfully managed to import a brutally large database (56M records - 15 hours to import), and written an app to work with it locally. I found an app, pgAdmin3, that lets me do all sorts of admin tasks with the GUI. All is good.

Every time I restart the computer, once it was due to a kernel panic from a USB firewire audio interface, once was from a power failure, and two were from user initiated restarts - each time after reboot, the database is empty. Database users/roles are still there, tables and relations are there, however, all the tables are empty. 0 records. Nothing. pgAdmin3 even shows that the table has space *allocated* for some number of millions of records, with an "undefined" count. Refreshing the count, reveals 0 records. Browsing the data reveals 0 records. My Mac application (using libpq) connects to the database successfully, and gets 0 results from any/all of its SELECT statements. Is it redundant to mention that each re-import of the database takes 15 hours? (rhetorical question)

Any and all suggestions appreciated.

Mac OS X 10.0.2 (Yosemite)
Homebrew 0.9.5
PostgreSQL 9.4.1 on x86_64-apple-darwin14.1.0, compiled by Apple LLVM version 6.0 (clang-600.0.56) (based on LLVM 3.5svn), 64-bit

Comment: Did you create them as `UNLOGGED` tables? If so, that's expected behaviour on unclean shutdown. Show `\d mytable` for one of the tables - does it say "Table mytable" or "Unlogged table mytable" ?

Comment: Yes, the tables are unlogged. It seems safe to assume, then, that tables you want to keep are logged, and I'm not thinking of a good use case for a table that is transient and can go away, but that would be why you use unlogged tables?

Comment: The manual explains that. Unlogged tables are great for data loading, materialized views, multi-session temp tables, etc. Especially cases when you can rebuild the data if you have to but it is time consuming so you would rather not. They have significant performance benefits and are also not replicated - which can avoid unnecessary replication overhead sometimes. Like most features it's just about using them sensibly and for the right things.

Comment: Craig thank you, I really should take more time to Read The Fine Manual, and when I have a moment I shall. I found an existing python script to import the database (a creative commons open license DB which is updated regularly & will be re-imported often), and said script declares all of the tables as UNLOGGED. What am I missing that tells the DB to not flush these across restart? Probably I am guessing that the normal Mac restart procedure is not tied in to shutting down the DB properly? I suppose I could make them all logged, but I am concerned what the performance concerns are. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 6):

The behaviour you describe would be consistent with your tables being `UNLOGGED`.

An unlogged table is halfway between a normal table and a temp table. It's like a normal table in that:

- It's usable from multiple sessions
- It isn't cleared when a session exits
- It's stored in the main tablespace, not the temp tablespace

but it's like a temp table in that:

- It isn't crash safe. The contents of `UNLOGGED` tables are preserved when PostgreSQL shuts down and restarts, but only if it's shut down cleanly. On unclean shutdown, `UNLOGGED` tables may be truncated, so they still exist but contain zero rows.
- Writing to it doesn't produce write-ahead log records in `pg_xlog`
- It can't be replicated to other nodes over streaming or log-based replication
- Writing to an unlogged table causes about half the disk I/O as a regular table

See [the manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createtable.html).

At a guess, your tables are defined as `UNLOGGED` and you aren't shutting PostgreSQL down cleanly when your Mac shuts down. So it's truncating the unlogged tables, since it can't be sure they're in a consistent state.

Shut PostgreSQL down cleanly (e.g. `pg_ctl -m fast -w stop`, or a launchd configuration that makes sue to do that). Or don't use unlogged tables. Or be willing to re-load your data when you restart.

Since you wondered what unlogged tables are for:

- They're great for data loading and transform, where you want to load a bunch of data, then extract and transform it for loading into other tables.
- Reporting tables
- Work queues and task queues for anything where the whole system can just be restarted, so you don't need to make the lists of in-progress tasks etc crash-safe

Comment: I'm also using UNLOGGED tables and I'm occasionally facing the same issue, despite the fact that I always perform a clean shutdown of postgresql via systemd service (`service postgresql restart`). The stop command in the unit file looks as follows: `ExecStop=/usr/bin/pg_ctlcluster --skip-systemctl-redirect -m smart %i stop`.  Any idea why the tables could get truncated during a restart?

Comment: @user35934 Based on that command it definitely shouldn't. Weird. Try running with a higher debug level for a while (`log_min_messages = 'debug2'` or similar). Also consider recording the output of `pg_controldata /path/to/your/postgres/datadir/` as a pre-start command in your startup script. If you see the issue happen again, report to the mailing list with the logs and the controldata output.

Comment: i also have noticed that sometimes after the 'fast' shutdown that i request still OCCASIONALLY the unlogged table data gets thrown away ... need to research more and check logs to see if it was some failure during the 'fast' shutdown, but need to take some more time to do that

Answer (score 0):

Craig Ringer's suggestion about UNLOGGED tables is great, the other thing to check is that you have committed whatever operation loaded the data.

Comment: Ron I'm a developer of many languages except **SQL and have not RTFM yet, so forgive my ignorance, how does one commit the operation that loaded the data. The steps I follow are: create db with python script that emit postgresql commands, import db with python/psycopg2 to read 20MB of XML (15 hours), run python script that emits SQL to index DB, run VACUUM ANALYZE; on data. I've done the ANALYZE SELECT foo FROM bar; thing enough times to figure out additional indices. I've got a Mac app banging the DB for good results and reasonably expect the thing to work on iOS, but I'm a Postgres neophyte…

Comment: I think you've got a few problems there, Walt :) That must be incredibly complex XML if it is taking 15 hours to load 20Mb, I typically see that size of data loading in seconds. I just read your response to Craig's suggestion, you need to get the UNLOGGED clause out of your CREATE queries. That will keep your data across reboots. Then we can look at your performance problem. Can you share the URL of the Python script that creates the database/tables?

Comment: Typo. Meant 20GB! I can easily sort through the python and change the creates to logged, that isn't an issue. I'm curious why the original author created it as unlogged (probably because he leaves his db up 24/7 and updates it every month?). Anyway the db is the public database from www.discogs.com (monthly data dumps at http://www.discogs.com/data/) and the import script is called discogs-xml2db  (found at https://github.com/philipmat/discogs-xml2db)